# Nodejs connect to mongoose failed on server(ubuntu 20.04), but worked on local

Tags: networking, server, nodejs, mongodb

I am able to connect my node.js app via MongoDB url provided by mongodb.com. But in the server(ubuntu 20.04), it,s not connecting.
I am sure the database URL is accurate on the server. Also the server ip is whitelisted in Mongodb.com.
[image]